# HTTPS not working outside localhost (outside network)

Tags: https, xampp

I have developed a php page and hosted it in my personal computer.

I am accessing the php page using my public ip address but I want to access it with HTTPS

but upon trying it, it does not load.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be easy with ngrok.

It's really easy to use and only takes few secs to run. It is as simple as downloading your system version. Unzip and run [ngrok.exe](https://ngrok.com/download). It will open a command line type of window. Make sure your Apache server or the one you use is running.

Then to only listen on an HTTPS tunnel endpoint run the following

> ngrok http -bind-tls=true site.dev:80

or on whatever port you need https to be installed.

Open browser and type https://localhost/myApp you will see it works.

And if you type http://localhost/myApp it also works.

Hope this is helpful to anyone for a fast solution.